# Sharepoint Auth to Livelink Auth

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication

Today I'm Facing a new issue which I must admit, i have no idea where to start..

I've been asked to Show certain Livelink files within Sharepoint.

Now, Livelink has a couple of web services (Luckily normal .net webservices) which would allow for authentication and it has one for retrieving the docs.

Now, All I'm worrying about for now, is the ability to pass the currently logged on SP User to the Livelink Auth Web Service. Here are the available Auth Methods in the livelink webservice:

```
        llAuthWebService.AuthenticateUser(username, password);

        llAuthWebService.AuthenticateUserWithApplicationToken(username, password, "");

        llAuthWebService.AuthenticateApplication(llAuthentication.OTAuthentication, "", "");
```

Any ideas?

Obviously I dont want to have the user retype his/her password while already authenticated via Sharepoint and NTLM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fox,

with normal NTLM authentication, you can't pass through your credentials, due to the double hop problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx.

what could you do?

- Maybe use claim authentication (dont know if livelink supports that?).
- configure kerberos (to overcome the double hop.). This can be a burden of pain ;)
- use the secure store service for SP2010 or Single Signon for MOSS2007. Here you can store credentials for any user

Additional question
 - Are the users already known in livelink? If yes: can they login in normal livelink via NTLM?

seeing the API above, option 3 *seems* to be the way to go, but because i dont have too much information about how livelink is configured and about your requirements, this doesnt *have* to be the way to go ;)

edit: do you only need to show files, and do they need to be security trimmed? If they dont need to be security trimmed you can do the following:

1. Create a design based on the trusted subsystem:
2. Configure BCS to read items from that livelink webservice as an External Content type
3. Configure an External list to show the live link items.

A security trimmed option could be:
Create a custom connector for SharePoint enterprise search or fast. Index your documents and show them to the user.

Comment: Thanks Bas. Your answer pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Can you leave your solution here? Always interesting!

Comment: Hi Bas. Unfortunately the solution is still to come. The answer pointed me in the right direction of what I need to develop, but nothing has been done yet. I will keep this one open and post the answer once dev is done :-)